# Getting Error: System.TypeException: Invalid conversion from runtime type List<ANY> to Map<String,ANY>

Tags: apex, json, wrapper-class, deserialize, serialize

I'm getting error in the following apex method: System.TypeException: Invalid conversion from runtime type List to Map<String,ANY>

Please find the apex method:

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)  
    public static void updateQuantity(String recordId, Object quantity){
        System.debug('recordId--------->' + recordId + 'quantity------->' + quantity);
        
        Map<String, Object> quantityWrapper = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(JSON.serialize(quantity));
               
        List<Map<String, Object>> quantityJSON = new List<Map<String, Object>>();
        
        for (Object instance : (List<Object>)quantityWrapper.get('quantityJSON'))
        quantityJSON.add((Map<String, Object>)instance);    
        
        system.debug('quantity:'+quantityJSON);
        
        
    }
```

JSON:
Following are the draftValues from LWC Component.

```
[
  {
    "splitQuantityValue": "30",
    "Id": "row-0"
  },
  {
    "splitQuantityValue": "30",
    "Id": "row-1"
  },
  {
    "splitQuantityValue": "30",
    "Id": "row-2"
  }
]
```

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message you're getting provides a good hint here

> System.TypeException: Invalid conversion from runtime type List to Map<String,ANY>`

In JSON, square braces `[]` indicate that you're working with an array, with *a List*. Curly braces `{}` indicate that you're working with an object, a `Map<String, Object>`.

Since the JSON you're working with starts with square braces, it's a List, and you  need to deserialize it *as a List*, so:

- `quantityWrapper` needs to be declared as a `List<Object>`
- you need to cast the result of `JSON.deserializeUntyped()` as a `List<Object>`
- you don't need the loop at all (unless you're trying to gather or sum the individual quantities)

Comment: Thank you @Derek F for the reply. It worked with the solution you provided. 

List<Object> quantityWrapper = (List<Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(JSON.serialize(quantity));

Thank you for your time.